# How to predict linear value based on future date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do i predict a value for future date using BigQuery ML?

Here is what i have tried.

Input Data:

```
Date         Value 
03-MAY-2020, 5
04-MAY-2020, 10
05-MAY-2020, 15
06-MAY-2020, 20
```

Create Linear regression model

```
CREATE MODEL
data.value_model OPTIONS(model_type='LINEAR_REG',
input_label_cols=['value']) AS
select date,value from data.test;
```

Then run ML predict

```
SELECT
*
FROM
ML.PREDICT(MODEL data.value_model,
(
select DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 10 DAY),value from data.test;
));
```

But the model predicts static value regardless of date being passed.

I have searched and not able to find any specific examples.

Comment: How much data are you training on and how long are you looking to forecast out?

Comment: @BenP I was trying to forecast for 2 years based on 20 year data.

Answer (score 2):

BQML does accept timestamp. You can convert date to timestamp first: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-weights#timestamp-transform.

Besides, this does look like a time series prediction use case. BQML is planning to add support for that soon with a different model type.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently BigQuery ML doesn't accept date columns. So I'd recommend to convert them to int64.

To convert dates to integer, I used 2020-01-01 as day 0 and I calculated the date difference to that day.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL
dataset.value_model OPTIONS(model_type='LINEAR_REG') AS
SELECT DATE_DIFF(date, '2020-01-01', day) as datediff, value as label
FROM (
  SELECT CAST('2020-05-03' AS DATE) as date, 5 as value union all
  SELECT CAST('2020-05-04' AS DATE) as date, 10 as value union all
  SELECT CAST('2020-05-05' AS DATE) as date, 15 as value union all
  SELECT CAST('2020-05-06' AS DATE) as date, 20 as value 
);


SELECT
    DATE_ADD('2020-01-01', interval datediff day) as date, predicted_label
FROM
ML.PREDICT(MODEL dataset.value_model,
(
    select DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, '2020-01-01', day) + day_add as datediff from UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10)) as day_add
));
```

Then, output looks like that:

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: While this approach is fine for linear growth, it doesn't work for exponential or variable growth, its sad the BigQuery ML doesn't accept date.

Comment: Why should it now work for exponential growth? You can calculate exponential values of diffdate column and train data with that column.